# delete string between two strings in one line

Tags: perl, awk, sed

i am trying to delete everything between bracket <>, i can do it if one line only has one <>, but if a line has more than one, it seems to delete everything inside the outer <>.

```
echo "hi, <how> are you" | sed 's/<.*>//' 
result: hi,  are you

echo "hi, <how> are <you>? " | sed 's/<.*>//' 
result: hi, ?
```

the first echo is working fine, but if one sentense has more than one <>, it can not classify.

```
expected input: 1 <a> 2 <b> 3 <c> 4 <d> ...... 1000 <n>
expected out come: 1 2 3 4 .... 1000
```

thanks

Comment: `<.*>` it should be  `<.*?>` or `<[^>]*>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
# using gsub - recommended 
$ echo "1 <a> 2 <b> 3 <c> 4 <d> ...... 1000 <n>" | awk 'gsub(/<[^>]*>/,"")' 
1  2  3  4  ...... 1000 

# OR using FS and OFS
$ echo "1 <a> 2 <b> 3 <c> 4 <d> ...... 1000 <n>" | awk -F'<[^>]*>' -v OFS='' '$1=$1'
1  2  3  4  ...... 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Following awk will be helpful to you.

```
echo "hi, <how> are <you>? "  | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/<.*>/){$i=""}}} 1'
```

OR

```
echo "1 <a> 2 <b> 3 <c> 4 <d> ...... 1000 <n>"  | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/<.*>/){$i=""}}} 1'
```

***Explanation:*** Simply going through all the fields of the line(by starting a for loop which starts from `i=1` to till the value of `NF`(number of fields)), there I am checking if a field's value is satisfying regex `<.*>`(means it has ) then I am nullifying it.

Answer (score 1):

`*` matches zero or more times with greedy. use the negation character class `<[^>]*>`

```
echo "hi, <how> are <you>? " | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```